# Woocommerce not showing any changes

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to edit the Woocommerce checkout page.

The file is located in

[image]

I did some changes in the form-checkout.php file but in my browser i get to see nothing at all! 
I even opened it in different browsers and opened the website in incognito mode.

I deleted all the php in form-checkout.php to see if i could see any changes but nope. I'm wondering if this is the right file to edit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not the way to make changes to any plugin. Never edit core plugin files. Read the manual. You will find you will have to copy files to your themes folder.

Comment: If you make this an answer ill accept it, helped me :) @RST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to make changes to any plugin.

*** Never edit core plugin files. ***

Changes will be lost on future updates.
Read the manual. You will find you will have to copy files to your themes folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok but not the best practice to modify WooCommerce templates.

WooCommerce has a [override template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) mechanism.
By doing so, your modifications will not be missing when you updating WooCommerce.

If you don't see any changes when you modifing the template file directly, your theme may have overridden WooCommerce templates.

You can check which template is overridden at wp-admin **WooCommerce->System Status** page. You can modify the files in your theme, or copy it to the child theme which is the better way.
[image]